# Change path in sql script with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, path

I'm trying to change the path in a oracle sql script from a bash script.

```
read -e -p "Enter the ORACLE SID: " -i "orcl" ORACLE_SID_VALUE
sed -i "DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl';/c\DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/${ORACLE_SID_VALUE}'" schema-install.sql
```

when I execute the script i get the following error:
*sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command*

can anyone please help me with the correct sed command.

---

more info

just to clarify:
in the file schema-install.sql, there is a line defining where the oracle database will stored.

DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl';

I want to change the value *orcl* to the value I type into the variable ORACLE_SID_VALUE.

Comment: what is this supposed to do?: `DEFINE tsdir = `?

Comment: It will define the directory where the Oracle database will be placed

Comment: Ok, but that's nonsense to `sed`. It *does* understand a `D` command, but no `DEFINE` and so on will be parsed will be parsed correctly. If that's to be part of a regex you've got to format it correctly.

Comment: The line in the sql script is: DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl';

Comment: That is the line you desire to change? And you wish to append the `$ORACLE_SID_VALUE` to the end of the path as Archemar has already shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
sed -i -e "/DEFINE tsdir = /c\
DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/${ORACLE_SID_VALUE}'
" schema-install.sql
```

`sed` is confused by / in path definition.

Comment: The error was that the line in the sql file had an TAB, that i did not see. It works now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you are trying to replace

```
DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl'
```

by

```
DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/${ORACLE_SID_VALUE}'
```

If this is what you are trying to do , You can achieve this using

```
sed -i "s#DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/orcl'#DEFINE tsdir = '/u02/app/oracle/oradata/${ORACLE_SID_VALUE}'#" schema-install.sql
```

Comment: sorry it does not work

Comment: it is working for me. Can you paste how you ran it and your output.

Comment: The error was that the line in the sql file had an TAB, that i did not see. It works now. thanks.